# Using a form twice returns warning

Tags: angular, typescript

Scenario:

I have a simple form template, with email and password. I'm using this form template for both Login and Signup purpose. But when I use the same form template twice, I'm getting a warning like

`[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #Email`

`[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #Password`

How to get rid of this warning.

Code:

**userform.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-userform',
  templateUrl: './userform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userform.component.css']
})
export class UserFormComponent {
  @Output() submitted: EventEmitter<UserModel> = new EventEmitter<UserModel>()
  userForm = new FormGroup({
    email : new FormControl(''),
    password : new FormControl('')
  });

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted.emit(this.userForm.value);
  }
}
```

**userform.component.html**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    Login
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" formControlName="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <app-userform (submitted)="loginUser($event)"></app-userform>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <app-userform (submitted)="CreateUser($event)"></app-userform>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  loginUser(user: UserModel) {
    console.log('Login User', user);
  }

  CreateUser(user: UserModel) {
    console.log('Create User', user);
  }
}
```

If I run this, everything is working, but getting the warning. I know that when the same template renders twice, there will be two same ids. Is there any way to customize the id, prefixed with a word?

For example, If the form is used as a login form, then the email id will be login-email, the password id will be login-password.

Comment: First, I really don't understand why you would have the same form twice in the page. But anyway, yes, components can have inputs, and you can use that input as a part of the IDs. Or you can simply use a static counter that you increment every time your component is created, and use that counter as part of your IDs.

Comment: Just remove the id assignment in the html and it will work. Why bother creating unique html ids on a dynamic form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JBNizet Mentioned in the comment you can use some variable to set dynamic id. So whenever component instantiated it will get increment

**userform.component.ts**

```
let instance=0;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-userform',
  templateUrl: './userform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userform.component.css']
})
export class UserFormComponent {
  @Output() submitted: EventEmitter<UserModel> = new EventEmitter<UserModel>()
  userForm = new FormGroup({
    email : new FormControl(''),
    password : new FormControl('')
  });
 constructor(){

 this.id=instance++;

 }
  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted.emit(this.userForm.value);
  }
}
```

**userform.component.html**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    Login
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email{{id}}" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" formControlName="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password{{id}}" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-instance